# Jade variable interpolation - default value if a property is undefined?

Tags: express, pug

I've got a form for updating user data that populates each input with the existing field value as it is stored in the database. However, in the case of new users, certain values haven't yet been committed to the database and so I'd like the input boxes to be blank.

In order to display the user data, I'm using Jade's interpolation functionality to look at the `#{user.local}` object passed in via the `routes.js` file.

It looks like this (snippet):

```
input(type="text", name="firstname", value="#{user.local.firstName}")
```

This works well when the property is defined, but it (correctly) inserts `undefined` as the text in an input where the property has not been defined.

Is there a way for me to set a variable to default to something if it hasn't been set?

Something like:

```
input(type="text", value="#{user.local.firstName || 'Default Text'"})
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have the exact same problem currently and searching for a solution.

Comment: Not in Jade, per se. I'm thinking I just need to add some logic to my controller so that, when it retrieves data, it replaces `undefined` with any empty string or whatever. Then that data would be passed to the view via the router.

Comment: Using jade ~1.9.2, ```input(type='text' class='form-control' id='line6Name' name='param6' value='#{device.param6||""}')``` gives a default of an empty string for undefined values when I do it. I'm willing to be the code you have there would work if you shifted where the closing double quote is.

Comment: I'll try that - why don't you write that as an answer so I can accept it if it works! Thanks @ZacharyJacobi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jade ~1.9.2, I tried

```
input(type='text' class='form-control' id='line6Name' name='param6' value='#{device.param6||""}')
```

in a form I'm writing. It gives a default of an empty string for undefined values.

I'm willing to bet the code you have there would work if you shifted where the closing double quote is.

From:

```
input(type="text", value="#{user.local.firstName || 'Default Text'"})
```

To:

```
input(type="text", value="#{user.local.firstName || 'Default Text'}")
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Turns out you were right - my curly brace should have terminated before the final quotation mark.